# Power BI - Insurance company with maximum profit statewise

Tags: powerbi, dax

The dataset has the insurance premium for various insurance companies in the States. How do I get to show the Insurance company from each state having the maximum profit?

I did not have anything to show for this. I thought I will need  a DAX for this, but I wasn't sure of there is a simple way.

Comment: How do you determine profit? Do you have payments that the insurance company makes on each policy or similar?

Comment: Yes, the profit would be the premium earned minus the claims paid.

Comment: so you create a measure to calculate total payments, and then another measures to calculate total premiums, and then you create a 3rd measure that calculates the difference.

Comment: Can't help further here without a specific example. Ultimately, you will most likely need to use DAX in a Measure or Calculated Column. You will probably need to use DAX functions like [RANKX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/rankx-function-dax) or [TOPN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/topn-function-dax).

Comment: Can you please add a sample dataset with your expected output?